Effect of group velocity dispersion (GVD) on pulse chirp
GVD at some frequency $\omega=\omega_0$ can be defined as
$$\text{GVD}=\frac{d^2k}{d\omega^2}\biggr\rvert_{\omega=\omega_0}=\frac{d}{d\omega}\left[\frac{1}{v_g(\omega)}\right]_{\omega=\omega_0}$$
When GVD is positive in a medium, an unchirped pulse becomes positively chirped after propagation.

(Image source: https://www.intechopen.com/chapters/51849)
The reason, according to many sources, is that

The long-wavelength
components of an optical pulse propagate faster than the short-wavelength
components when the group velocity dispersion ... is positive, and
vice versa.

(Quoted from Nonlinear Optics by Boyd)
But how can this be shown mathematically? How fast a frequency/wavelength-component moves depends on its phase velocity, but GVD is directly related to group velocity, not phase velocity.

I like this question: have you given it any thought? What about $dv_g/dk$?

@JEB, Yes, I have thought about this quite a lot. Apparently, when they say that in a medium with positive GVD, some frequency components travel faster than others, they are simply comparing their frequency-dependent group velocities, not phase velocities.

@JEB, The following argument may show why phase velocity is not important in this case: A given pulse may be written mathematically as an integral of plane waves of different frequencies. Each of these plane waves extends from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ with infinite number of crests and troughs. So when one of these waves has a higher phase velocity compared to another wave, it doesn't mean that one is (or will be) in front of the other.

So take two sheet of paper, stacked. Tilt the top sheet slightly so there is point $A$ where they overlap. Now move the top sheet left and right. How fast does $A$ move ($v_A$)? I bet you, in your new desktop lab, can achieve $v_A > c$. Can you transmit information by moving $A$? That's phase velocity.

I believe what you are looking for is the Rayleigh relation between phase and group velocity. I think this resource I found online has a clear and concise discussion on it. This relation is:
$$\nu_{group}(\omega)=\nu_{phase}\left(1-\frac{\omega}{\nu_{phase}}\frac{d\nu_{phase}}{d\omega} \right)$$
However, to clarify the reason to consider the group velocity and not the phase velocity is that the ensemble of phase velocities the constituent frequencies that comprise the pulse have is what changes the envelope of the pulse. In other words, the amount of "spreading" a pulse experiences is dependent on both the bandwidth of the pulse and the dispersive strength of the medium. This can be seen from where the GVD originates from, the Taylor expansion of the spectral phase of the pulse:
$$\begin{gather} \label{eq:phiw}
\phi(\omega)= \phi_0 +\frac{n(\omega)\omega}{c}\cdot L=\phi_0+k(\omega)\cdot L \\
k(\omega)=k(\omega_0)+k'(\omega_0)(\omega-\omega_0)+\frac{k''(\omega_0)}{2}(\omega-\omega_0)^2+\frac{k'''(\omega_0)}{6}(\omega-\omega_0)^3+...
\end{gather}$$
Where $k''(\omega)=\frac{d^2k}{d\omega^2}$. Note that the Taylor series is explicit in this bandwidth argument. For an appreciable amount of accumulated spectral phase, the bandwidth $(\omega-\omega_0)$ must be sufficient to contribute. Further reading on ultrafast dispersion is in any ultrafast optics textbook (Ultrafast Optics by Weiner), but I think the most accessible discussion on this is Potma's Foundations of Nonlinear Optical Microscopy.
I hope this helps.

Thanks. It takes me a while to process this, but I think the answer (including the first equation) needs some editing.
